# ¿Por qué me produce esta excepción? C++ Stocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, socket, excepciones

Estoy **intentando aprender** a hacer conexiones TCP en C++ con Sockets, por lo que hay bastantes cosas que no me quedan claras.

Quiero modificar el Socket `sock_CONNECTION` para que este en estado de "No bloqueo", sin embargo esta es la parte del codigo donde me tira la  excepción
de no poder leer la memoria

> ioctlsocket(sock_CONNECTION, FIONBIO, NON_BLOCK_MODE);

Donde NON_BLOCK_MODE es una variable de tipo u_long = 00000001

Declaracion del socket:

> SOCKET sock_CONNECTION;
>   sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa la documentación de [`socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx). Los valores válidos para el tercer parámetro son:

- `SOCK_STREAM` (1)
- `SOCK_DGRAM` (2)
- `SOCK_RAW` (3)
- `SOCK_RDM` (4)
- `SOCK_SEQPACKET` (5)

... donde el número entre paréntesis es el valor que suele sustituir al nombre que le precede.

Ahora bien, tu estás creando el socket así:

```
sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
//                                             ^^^^
```

... donde `NULL` es un alias de `0`, valor que no figura en la lista anterior.

Lo que falla aquí no es la configuración del bloqueo del socket sino la creación del propio socket. Esto lo habrías visto en seguida si hubieses verificado el valor devuelto por `socket`:

```
sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
if (sock_CONNECTION == INVALID_SOCKET) {
  // Error al crear el socket...
}
```

La solución pasa por usar un valor válido en la llamada a `socket`. ¿Qué valor? pues dependerá del tipo de conexión que intentes crear. Como no has indicado nada al respecto queda en tu mano elegir la configuración correcta.